# Drupal uploading files to server

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal (using ver 7.22).  I created a test site on my localhost and want to upload it to the server (via FTP).  I understand how to export the local drupal database and import it on the server... and how to update settings.php. My question is, what folders / files do I upload to the server?  My drupal files are in www/drupal.  I have searched for an answer and it sounds like you're supposed to upload the whole drupal folder (all files, subfolders).  That seems like overkill.  For example, if I add a of couple article nodes locally and then want to update the server, I'm supposed to upload the entire drupal folder?  I'm used to the standard web model where I upload individual files (.htm, .php, .css) as needed.

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal, individual nodes are stored in the database, and don't actually have a code file (html, php, etc.). So you upload all you code (entire drupal folder), and if you add nodes locally, you just need to sync the database on your production site with the one on your local site. I use a module called Backup & Migrate to migrate databases from one site to another. The only time you should need to FTP files back and forth is if you modify the actual code itself.

Comment: Thanks. What about modules and themes? If I add a module or theme locally, do I also add it on the server or do I transfer it to the server via the database or files?

Comment: You have to add them to the code on your production (live) site. But if you make any changes to the module (activate it, change a setting, etc.), all those changes are stored in the database and will need to be brought over as well.